# json data not rendering

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm new to D3js and having consistent problems working with json files. This issue has me very confused. I posted an example on:

http://jsfiddle.net/tommy6s/m5dfmf5r/

I have been working in the console and have tried the following as well as every other combination that I can think of:

```
 console.log(data) //returns data
 console.log(data.value); //returns undefined 
 console.log(d.value); //returns d is not defined
 console.log(data[0].value); //returns  67.53 first single value
```

I also get a console error: `TypeError: string.slice is not a function
var n = d3_time_numberRe.exec(string.slice(i, i + 4));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the dates you are returning are pretty much all null.

Do the following in your example as a test for this:

```
data.forEach(function(d) {
    console.log(d);
    d.date = parseDate(d.date);
    d.value = +d.value;
 });
```

You'll notice it fails after trying one. Each of the dates from d.date is null. Causing the parseDate function to fail.

Down in your type function I changed it to use the javascript new Date instead to convert it and removed the second call to parseDate in the forEach loop to fix that.

```
function type(d) {
        var obj = {};
         console.log(d);
        obj.date = new Date(d[0]); //Use the javascript date object is perhaps better?
        obj.value = d[1];

        return obj;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/m5dfmf5r/5/

Comment: Thank you very much Rezant! I'm not sure I would have figured this one out.

Comment: Not a problem, I definitely think Max answers your actual question better however.

Answer (score 2):

An element in d.data array has the following structure:

> ["2015-02-28", 67.53, 68.67, 67.05, 67.68, 0.0, 67.68 ]

[image]

I am not sure why this is not a JSON object (with field-value pair) but in order to access it you need to do something as below:

```
function(error, d) {
  var data = d.data;
  data.forEach(function(d) {
    var date   = parseDate(d[0]);
    var open = d[1];
    var high = d[2];
    ..
    var close= d[6];
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help Max! I agree with you about the JSON. I think that's part of what was confusing me.

Comment: The screen is taken from the JsonViewer free program http://jsonviewer.software.informer.com/1.2/